# combining two dataframes sorted by common columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've been stuck on this for a while - I have tried merging, concatenating, joins, but can't get what I want.

given the two dataframes :

[image]

I want to combine them to get :

[image]

First I want them aligned  by Start Location. If the names can be aligned, that is a bonus, but not critical. Although this example looks like the 2nd table is aligning to the 1st, it could be either way, depending on the Start Location.The two dataframes are appropriately sorted beforehand. I can't even figure this out with two dataframes, but ultimately I want to be able to combine several together.

Comment: `pd.concat([df1.set_index('Match Name'), df2.set_index('Match Name')], axis=1)`?

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I want. Will this work if there are duplicate Match Names in df1 or df2 ?